# (a*b)/256 and MMX

Tags: assembly, sse, mmx

I'm wondering if it is possible to do the following calculation with four values parallel within a MMX-Register:

```
(a*b)/256
```

where **a** is a signed word and **b** is an unsigned value (blend factor) in the range of 0-256

I think my problem is that I'm not sure about how (or if) *pmullw* and *pmulhw* will help me with this task.

Comment: Does this have to be done with just MMX? It's pretty outdated.

Comment: so how can it be done faster?

Comment: You can do 8 values in parallel with SSE2, instead of just the 4 with MMX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that a*b won't overflow a signed 16-bit field, then you can use pmullw (intrinsic `_mm_mullo_pi16`, or SSE intrinsic `_mm_mullo_epi16`) and then shift right by 8 to do the division by 256.

Where

MMX:

```
__m64 a, b;
...
a = _mm_mullo_pi16 (a, b);
a = _mm_srli_pi16 (a, 8);
```

SSE2:

```
__m128i a, b;
...
a = _mm_mullo_epi16 (a, b);
a = _mm_srli_epi16 (a, 8);
```

Comment: The problem is, that a*b **will** overflow a 16-bit field. Is there a way to get that managed anyway? I'll have a closer look on SSE2. Thanks mattst88!

Comment: If a*b overflows 16-bit, then you can shift either a or b to the left by 8 bit, and then do pmulhw.

Comment: The result will be correct because those bits of the result only depends on the lower bits of a and b